# Calculate column sequence length per group using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My data frame looks as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Group = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C"),
  Date = as.Date(c("2023-01-01","2023-01-02","2023-01-03","2023-01-01","2023-01-02","2023-01-01","2023-01-02","2023-01-03")),
  B = c(1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1)
)
```

For each group I want to summarize the length of the most recent sequence of 1's where the 1's run all the way to the max date per group. I'm only looking to summarize the length of the continuous string a 1's, a 0 anywhere breaks the chain.

In my example above, when summarized Group A and B will return both a value of zero while C will have a value of 3. Working back from the most recent date the 1's run for a length of 3.

How can this be achieved using dplyr?

A and B are both broken by the 0 in their max date

Comment: Something using `rle` will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I rearrange to start from the most recent observations, then only include rows above (chronologically after) the first B==0. Then I count rows by group, and add back 0s for groups with n=0.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(Group, desc(Date)) %>%
  filter(cumsum(B == 0) == 0, .by = Group) %>%
  count(Group) %>%
  tidyr::complete(Group = unique(df$Group), fill = list(n = 0))

  Group     n
  <chr> <int>
1 A         0
2 B         0
3 C         3
```